# flex4 with php, error referencing function

Tags: php, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I'm trying to connect to MySql database in flex4. I wrote a php class like this,

```
public function getNames() {
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
      "SELECT
          names.firstname,
          names.middlename,
          names.lastname
       FROM names");     

  $this->throwExceptionOnError();

  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $this->throwExceptionOnError();

  $rows = array();
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->firstname, $row->middlename,
                $row->lastname);

  while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $rows[] = $row;
      $row = new stdClass();
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->firstname, $row->middlename,
                $row->lastname);
  }

  mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);
  mysqli_close($this->connection);

  return $rows;
```

}

I just dragged and droped a datagrid into flex design mode. Then using data-> connect to php option, i selected file name.php from webroot. Then flex4 is giving this error, I have no clue about it, since it generated various services.

What is the flex expecting now?

```
 protected function dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
                {
                    getNamesResult.token = name.getNames();
                }
```

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getNames through a reference with static type String. flexphp.mxml    /flexphp/src    line 12 Flex Problem

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a function directly in PHP without having some kind of layer that can communicate with Flex since PHP functions aren't publicly available.  You should look into [AMFPHP](http://amfphp.sourceforge.net/) or [ZendPHP](http://www.zend.com/en/) which provides this communication layer (amf remoting).